# loop when creating a new method

Tags: r

I am studying Advanced R from Hadley and he shows the example below:

```
new_secret <- function(x = double()) {
  stopifnot(is.double(x))
  structure(x, class = "secret")
}

print.secret <- function(x, ...) {
  print(strrep("x", nchar(x)))
  invisible(x)
}
```

that's when he tries to create a `[.secret` method:

```
`[.secret` <- function(x, i) {
  new_secret(x[i])
}
```

Could someone explain to me why this method, when called, goes into a loop?

```
x <- new_secret(c(15, 1, 456))

x[1]
```